# Moving from One Fragment to another activity Using ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent

I am using navigation drawer which moves from fragment to another when on clicked on the menu_item in it.
In one of my fragments i have a listview.
I have to move to another ACTIVITY and not FRAGMENT when clicked on one of the list view item
here is the code of both the things the Activity as well as fragment.
I have used intent but still it gives error on the parameters of intent.

"One" Fragment
   package com.navigate2;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;


 /**
  * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
  */
  public class One extends Fragment {


  public One() {
      // Required empty public constructor
  }


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView)listView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list2);
    listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(One.this,AndroidClass.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}


}
```

"AndroidClass" Activity

```
   package com.navigate2;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.PersistableBundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

  /**
  * Created by Nathani Aliakbar on 06-01-2016.
  */
  public class AndroidClass extends AppCompatActivity
  {
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.textview);
  }
  }
```

Comment: use getActivity() instead of One.this in intent @Ali Akbar

Comment: A `return` statement will exit the method - calling `return` immediately in `onCreateView()` means the rest of your code in that method is unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change **onCreateView()**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

ListView listView = (ListView)   rootview.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list2);

listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(One.this,AndroidClass.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});

 return rootview;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside fragment onCreateView you are returning immediately before adding onItemCliclListener:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
```

Try like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
ListView listView = (ListView)listView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list2);
listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                Intent intent = new Intent(One.this,AndroidClass.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
return view;
```

Comment: Done gives error = listview have not been initialized

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
  ListView listView = (ListView)listView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list2);
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),AndroidClass.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


return view;
```

Comment: I did this gives error like this                                                            ListView listView = (ListView)listView.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list2);//Error=Unreachable statement

Comment: Error:(32, 18) error: unreachable statement
Error:(46, 5) error: missing return statement
Error:(32, 39) error: variable listView might not have been initialized
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.mobile_list2);
listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(One.this,AndroidClass.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
});
return view;
```

Comment: Please add a description of why this is an answer to the question. This answer has been marked as low-quality, because of code only answer.