# OnClickListener in fragment doesn't work. Intent from fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, onclicklistener

Maybe it will be the same or duplicating question of this:
[Moving from One Fragment to another activity Using ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691437/moving-from-one-fragment-to-another-activity-using-listview)

But i have a problem on jumping from fragment to activity. I have the main activity with standard build navigation drawer which replaces my custom fragment with content_main fragment. In my fragment I want to set OnClickListener on TextView to jump to another activity. But it doesn't work! I can't solve this problem in 2 days and hope you'll help me.

my code of fragment:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment{

    public LoginFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);

        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.regLink);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

login_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/login_button_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/color_main"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/accountCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/account_check_text"
            android:textColor="@color/color_main"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/regLink"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sign_up_reference_text"
            android:textColor="@color/color_link"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to make intent to the RegistrationActivity:

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration_activity);

        Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.reg_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        setTitle("Registration");
    }
}
```

and the registration_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/bg_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/reg_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/bg_main"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/color_main"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

On the Logcat i see the next error:

```
09-20 10:37:42.462 31323-31323/com.alg E/CliptrayUtils: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()
```

I tried to set this listener on the button for the experiment, but I did't have the success. Then i tried to make intent to my activity from the other nav drawer's item, but it didn't work too.

It's just an empty white screen! Can you help me please?

Comment: In RegistrationActivity you have overriden wrong `onCreate` method. 

Replace `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)`
with `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Comment: Did you try to debug problem, add brakepoint and see what is going on.

Comment: Oh my god!! I'm stupid..It works now!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Button view for this action ??

Or add this code in your TextView xml:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```